# How do 2 or more elements share 1 css class selector?

Tags: html, css

is there a way for 2 or more elements to share one class css selector?

for example

```
p.hometown { 
    background: yellow;
}
```

what if div will also use hometown class? So only div and p will use class hometown.

Comment: the example shown is an element specific selector meaning only `p` elements with the class name of `hometown` will be targetted not `div`s....

Comment: what if only p and div can use the class?

Comment: then just use `.hometown { 
    background: yellow;
}` but make sure all the elements you want to target have the same class attribute of `hometown`.

Comment: I want to restrict usage of class only for p and div

Comment: `p.hometown, div.hometown { 
    background: yellow;
}`  ?

Comment: I think that's the answer, just to verbose it seems @Ousmane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the p

p.hometown says you only want to apply that rule to `<p>`  elements using that class

```
.hometown { 
    background: yellow;
}
```

will apply the class to all elements with class="hometown".

```
p.hometown, div.hometown {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Will apply the class to just `<div>` and `<p>` elements with the class

Comment: what if I only want it for p and div?

Comment: You don't need to specify the element unless you have different rules for the 'hometown' class for different elements. If you want to apply one rule to just `<p>` and `<div>`  it would be: p.hometown, div.hometown { etc }. In other words, you just put a comma between the selectors